# Is there a SonarQube rule to validate JavaDoc's?

Tags: validation, sonarqube, javadoc

I found a rule that makes sure JavaDoc's exist for public methods -> "**Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented with Javadoc**", however, it doesn't appear to validate the param names are correct. For example, the JavaDoc below should fail because 'badName' does not match 'aParam'. Is there another rule I can use to validate JavaDoc's are documented correctly?

```
/**
 * @param badName String
 */
public void myMethod(String aParam) {}
```

Comment: I am a little bit irrelevant., but try Doxygen http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/ you can generate nice output documentation, but most of all it verifies your javadoc syntax.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules in the SonarJava plugin that validate JavaDoc parameter names. Searching for [all available Java rules](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html), there are only three that are directly related to JavaDoc:

1. [Deprecated elements should have both the annotation and the Javadoc tag](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-1123)
2. [Public types, methods and fields (API) should be documented with Javadoc](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-1176)
3. [Packages should have a javadoc file 'package-info.java'](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-1228)

However, if you install the [Checkstyle plugin](https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle), you get some more Javadoc rules that may be close enough to what you are looking for. Here are some of their [JavaDoc checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/checks.html):

- JavadocMethod: Checks the Javadoc of a method or constructor.
- JavadocPackage: Checks that all packages have a package documentation.
- JavadocParagraph: Checks Javadoc paragraphs.
- JavadocStyle: Custom Checkstyle Check to validate Javadoc.
- JavadocTagContinuationIndentation: Checks the indentation of the continuation lines in at-clauses.
- JavadocType: Checks the Javadoc of a type.
- JavadocVariable: Checks that a variable has Javadoc comment.